# Can indoor cable be connected to outdoor cable of the same gauge?

Tags: outdoor

i want to run power to my shed but i can cover about 1/2 the distance from my panel to the shed by running wire through the house. I've got a bunch of regular 14-2 cable left over from a previous wiring job so rather than running the whole job in underground cable, i'd rather just buy outdoor cable for the part that's outdoor. just wondering if you know if this is allowed. I'd splice the lines together using a junction box.

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem doing what you want, as long as the junction is in a dry location.